# Apple watch forces open app in foreground on iphone on particular screen?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, foreground, watchconnectivity

Is it possible to make apple watch force opening iphone app and/or opening on particular screen?

I have already found out that it runs app in background (but doesn't show that the app is already launched) and even can download data. When I tap the app icon on iphone - the app skips splash screen and "appdidfinishlaunching..." step.

Comment: It isn't super clear as to what you are asking specifically. Do you want the watch extension to be able to force your iPhone app into the foreground, or open to a specific screen on the iPhone the next time it is opened after communicating with the watch?

Comment: No. I read the documentation and found this method: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1619531-openparentapplication?language=objc   "This method is only available for WatchKit extensions running in watchOS 1. Watch apps running in watchOS 2 or later must use the Watch Connectivity framework to communicate with the companion iOS app. For more information, see WatchConnectivity." And I don't know what to do with watchos 2 and later

Answer (score 1):

openParentApplication() has in fact been deprecated. The new convention is to use WatchConnectivity. [This link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity) will help to give you some information and [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SimpleWatchConnectivity/Introduction/Intro.html) is Apple's sample project for Watch Connectivity. Specifically to answer your question you will want to use the sendMessage() function from your watch extension to make a request which will wake up the corresponding iOS application in the background and allow it to return the requested data.

Here is a small example of a message request that will activate your iOS application in the background. However, you will need to setup Watch Connectivity in your application first.

In your watch extension

```
func sendActivationMessage() {
    if session.activationState == .activated && session.isReachable {
        session.sendMessage(["Watch Message" : "Activate"], , replyHandler: nil, errorHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

In your iOS Application

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {
    if let messageFromWatch = message["Watch Message"] {
        let messageData = messageFromWatch as! String

        if messageData == "Activate" {
           // Handle Request
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You posted info how to send messages from watch to iOS app in background. But it doesn't answer the question - "How to activate iOS app in foreground?"

Comment: There is no way to force open an application on your iOS device from the apple watch. Only in the background.

Comment: Even when openParentApplication() was available it would only allow you to access the application in the background as well

Comment: Using this when the parent app receives message, you can set a local notification to user for invoking the app.